# Confused about getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, html

Confused about the `getBoundingClientRect()` function in Javascript.

According to the official document, if `const rect = getBoundingClientRect();`, then we have

```
rect.width = rect.right - rect.left;

rect.height = rect.bottom - rect.top;
```

Does it means the left right position are left inclusive and right exclusive, i.e. [left, right)? Otherwise it should be

```
rect.height = rect.bottom - rect.top + 1;
```

Look at the following `5x5` map.
In `[inclusive, inclusive]` mode, the bounding rect all the `1`s should be `left=2, right=4, top=3, bottom=4`,
and we have

```
width=right-left+1=4-2+1
height=bottom-top+1=4-3+1
```

5x5 Grid

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
```

**A more specified question:**

what does `rect.left` mean? Does it mean that the distance to left of client container or the `i`th pixel? What about `rect.right`?

Comment: `0` is also a value of the placement.

Comment: More questions are added.

Comment: All these are explained in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) (you said you've read?).

Comment: I just come from the document page and get confused.  Is the question clear? or it should be more specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider it this way :

[image]

If the gray square represents screen space, then the red square has bounding box :

```
{
  x: 1, y: 1,
  width: 3, height: 3
}
```

Which means that it has `left=1`, `right=4`, and therefore, `right-left=width`

Comment: Great, I catch a bug in my code! Is there an official document, e.g. somewhere in mdn, explains such details. I can not find any [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getClientRects).

Comment: The best I can find is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSSOM_View/Coordinate_systems . Basically, you must not number pixels in your mind, but consider that pixels are 1-wide squares positioned at integer coordinates in a continuous space.  It is pretty common to have decimal values for object coordinates on screen. Then pixels are just an approximation of that for display purposes

Comment: Or rather: pixels as a unit of measurement (px) are not the same thing as actual pixels on your display. The latter are discrete squares, which leads to your initial reasoning. The former are just coordinates in a continuous space, which becomes more obvious when you zoom in (measured positions won't match screen pixels anymore, and will often be non-integers)

Comment: Yes, this is really different from the the pixel position system that I use before. Your explanation is really helpful.